# infinite loop in C when the user enters a character instead of a number

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, scanf, do-while

I have a problem, I want to make the user enter a digit from 1.00 to 10.00 and if he enters a digit outside of that range I will display that he was wrong and try again. I think I have done well but the problem is if the user enters a letter the loop repeats at infinity, I would appreciate your help. Thank you. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    float a;

    do
    {
        printf("Insert number between 1.00 and 10.00:\n");
        scanf("%f", &a);

        if (a < 1.00 || a > 10.0)
        {
            printf("Insert a correct number.\n");
        }
    } while (a < 1.00 || a > 10.00);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` returns a value. You need to check it to see whether it was able to read anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf leaves the '\n' char in the input stream so you need to skip it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    float a;

    do
    {
        printf("Insert number between 1.00 and 10.00:\n");
        scanf(" %f", &a);

        if (a < 1.00 || a > 10.0)
        {
            printf("Insert a correct number.\n");
        }
    } while (a < 1.00 || a > 10.00);

    printf("\nyou have entered: %f\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/baPxdn .But it does not sort out the wrong input problem.

I personally prefer to read the line and then scan it (and it does sort all the problems out):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    float a;

    do
    {
        printf("Insert number between 1.00 and 10.00:\n");
        fgets(str, 100, stdin);
        if(sscanf(str, " %f", &a) != 1) continue;

        if (a < 1.00 || a > 10.0)
        {
            printf("Insert a correct number.\n");
        }
    } while (a < 1.00 || a > 10.00);

    printf("\nyou have entered: %f\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vxY7To

Comment: Does the second solution have any advantages?

Comment: @Majkl the first one only consumes whitespace

Comment: `%f` already consumes leading whitespace , so your first program has identical behaviour to the OP program (except for the final output statement obviously)

Comment: @M.M True about "first program has identical behaviour", yet that is a lead in to "But it does not sort out the wrong input problem" and the 2nd code.  True that the space is `" %f"` is redundant.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica why post an identical program as a lead-in ? I think it is misleading as it is prefixed by the comment "scanf leaves the '\n' char in the input stream so you need to skip it:"  , so the OP might read that and think that adding the space  has some effect. Which it doesn't.  In fact there never was any problem with '\n' chars . The only problem is with not handling letters correctly .

Answer (score 1):

When you try to run `scanf()` on invalid input, it will not update `a` because it's impossible, so your loop will continue forever since `a` is never updated and the `scanf` function will fail forever, nothing is actually "read" by `scanf`, and never will never get past the invalid input.

Make sure you handle the invalid inputs by "consuming" them before repeating the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the result of the 'scanf', and "clean" the IO stream buffer once something error happen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define CLEAN_STD_STREAM() \
 do{\
   int ch; \
   while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); \
 }while(0)

int main()
{
    float a;

    do
    {
        printf("Insert number between 1.00 and 10.00:\n");
        if(scanf("%f", &a) != 1)
        {
          CLEAN_STD_STREAM();//fflush() dosen't work on the Linux
          continue;
        }

        if (a < 1.00 || a > 10.0)
        {
            printf("Insert a correct number.\n");
        }
    } while (a < 1.00 || a > 10.00);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```